# kmlcov package in R, for longitudinal data clustering, how to get predicted clusters?

Tags: r, longitudinal

```
library(kmlcov)
res <- glmClust(formula = latency ~ clust(time),
                data = data, ident = 'id', timeVar = 'time', nClust = 2)
```

How do I get for each id the predicted cluster they belong to?

Answer (score 1):

The predicted cluster is called *partition* in the `kmlcov` package. You can get it in the following way:

```
res <- glmClust(formula = Y ~ clust(time + time2 + time3) + pop(treatTime),
data = artifdata, ident = 'id', timeVar = 'time', effectVar = 'treatment', nClust = 4)

res@partition
```

Comment: @ Gloria Dalla Costa - Has my answer solved the problem? If so, please consider accepting it. Thanks